# How to post JSON Array to server in android via retrofit2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

How do I post a json array with retrofit2?

For example,

```
http://www.test.com/post/listparam=[{id=1,name="A"},{id=2,name="B"}]
```

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass any json,pass pojo class or bean class

For Example if your json is like this

```
 {
  "main":{"id":"1","name":"A"}

}
```

Then paste your json string in [jsonshematopojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/),
In source type click JSON radio button,In Annotation style select Gson and also click include constructers(You can download your generated bean classes by clicking Zip button).Then instead of passing json pass like this

```
new Example(new Main(id,name));
```

Instead of declaring `String` parameter in interface declare `Example`(Your main bean class name